# error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:/wamp64/cacert.pem CApath: none using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I realise there are similar threads but I have followed their guidance and am still having problems.

I have the following php code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$auth = curl_exec($curl);
echo $auth;
echo curl_error($curl);
```

where `$url` is a string without white space.

This generates the error:

`SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Inserting into the php script the line:

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` does indeed remove the error, but obviously this is not an ideal solution.

I have downloaded the cacert.pem file from here: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and have tried inserting the line:

`curl.cainfo = "C:/wamp64/cacert.pem"` to the end of the php.ini file (and also the phpForApache file in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.0 but this generated the same error):

`error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:/wamp64/cacert.pem CApath: none`

Thanks in advance

Comment: While that file has a lot of common root and intermediate certificate authority signing certs, I've found it lacks some really new ones from a few large sites.  I would suggest extracting the CA cert directly from the site you are trying to connect to using your web browser and then pointing cURL to just the root certificate for the site in question for these requests.

Comment: @drew010 sorry for taking so long to get back to you, how exactly do I do that? 
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt");` throws the same error `CAfile ... path:none` cheers

Comment: You can't specify a url for the CAINFO file, it has to be local, so download the contents of that file and save it to your system and then point it to that.

Comment: I did this `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:/wamp64/www/GIAG2.crt");` but it still gives the same error

Comment: Does the cert you downloaded begin with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` or is it in binary?

Comment: binary I think? It has ETX and STX and SOH all over it, but there are some readable bits too.

Comment: That might be why.  Instead try what's pasted here: http://pastebin.com/N7cFJuD0  I downloaded that cert, and converted it to PEM format.

Comment: I now get the error `SSL certificate problem: unable to get issuer certificate` again

Comment: What url are you trying to connect to, if you're able to say?

Comment: its a google maps api url `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=...`

Comment: The Google CA cert is ultimately signed by GeoTrust, so you are probably missing that cert.  Try this one in addition to the google one: http://pastebin.com/B4ejZva2  You can put both certs in one file, but really only need the GeoTrust one.

Comment: @w1nter Hi, I had the exact same problem, getting `error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:/wamp64/cacert.pem CApath: none` after downloading the `caret.pem` file. Did you found a "universal" solution, to use curl without having to point to each `crt` URL every time ? Thanks

Comment: @drew010 Hi there, sorry to bother, but I think you can help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157188/ssl-certificate-error-in-curl), since you helped w1nter. Any tips will help a lot. Thank you

Comment: @slevin I have the line curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $path); where path is the path to the caret.pem. Is that what you mean by having to point to each crt URL each time? I can't really give you much more information than that i'm afraid