# SSL certificate error in cURL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

**Facts**

I have Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.2.0beta3 on Win 10 laptop. I want to implement cURL. This is my code

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.youtube.com');
curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_errno ( $curl )) {
    echo curl_error ( $curl );
    curl_close ( $curl );
}
```

that generates the error `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`. So I downloaded certificates from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. Took the cacert.pem file, put it in the PHP folder and edited the `php.ini` file like this
`curl.cainfo = C:php/ext/cacert.pem`.

**Problem**

Now I get this error `error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:php/ext/cacert.pem CApath: none`. I googled and the only solution I found is that I have to download the `.crt` file from the site I want to cURL and include it in my cURL like `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:/wamp64/www/GIAG2.crt");`.

*Problem 1.1* : 
I dont know how to download the `.crt` file so I can include it in my code, like the above example.

*Problem 1.2* : That is not a "universal" solution, I want to set my certificates in such way that I dont have to download different certificates for different site.

Thank you

Comment: I was also getting the `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` problem and like you, I got the cacert.pem and linked to it in my php.ini. Worked perfectly for me. The only difference is I have PHP 5.6.

Comment: The current error is saying it can't set the certificate locations.  `C:php/ext/cacert.pem` should probably be `C:/php/ext/cacert.pem`  Then it should at least find it.  After, can you post the result if it works or not?  The current curl cacert.pem you referenced has the GeoTrust Global CA cert in it so it should validate YouTube fine.

Comment: @drew010 Works even with `curl.cainfo = C:/php/cacert.pem`, the detail is, I was ommiting a `/` after `C:`. I forgot about the oldest rule in the book. Thanks for your answer. You can post it as a normal one, so I can upvote you and choose it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current CA Cert extracts provided by [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) contain the GeoTrust Global CA certificate authority which signed Google's CA cert which in turn signs YouTube's cert, so you should have no problem using the file you have.

Based on the last error, it looks like the problem is because you were missing the `/` after `C:`.  The message `error setting certificate verify locations` means that it couldn't open or read the file specified by `curl.cainfo` so it's not finding any certs at all.

If you change `C:php/ext/cacert.pem` to `C:/php/ext/cacert.pem` it should be able to read the CA file correctly and then verify the site properly.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to skip this check.

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: That's rather crappy advice as it makes the connection insecure.

Comment: I know I have that option too, but I am asking for the certificates, not how too skip them. Thanks anyway